# Hibernate LEFT JOIN FETCH with ON clause or alternative

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a parent child relationship.

The parent class has the following fields `(id, name)` and the child class has the following columns `(id, name, date, parent_id)`. The end resulting JSON I want to return is the following. I also always want to return the parent even if it has no children, which is why I `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the child with the `ON` clause there

```
[

{
    "name": "parnet1",
    "child": {
      "2021-01-01": {
        "name": "child1"
      },
      "2021-01-02": {
        "name": "child2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "parnet2",
    "child": {}
    }
  }
]
```

Example of what my DB looks like for this sample

`parents`

```
id    |     name
1     |     parent 1
2     |     parent 2
```

`child`

```
id    |     name    |    date    |    parent_id
1     |     child1  |  2021-01-01|    1
2     |     child2  |  2021-01-02|    1
3     |     child3  |  2020-12-31|    2
```

For the following example I am passing the dat of 2021-01-01

So the month is January (1) and the year is 2021

In the parent class I have a map of this to reference the child

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
@MapKey(name = "date")
private Map<LocalDate, Child> children;
```

And here is the query I have

```
@Query("select p from Parent p left join p.child c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth
```

The problem with this is there is a 2nd query run after automatically by hibernate which is the following:

```
select * from Child where c.parent_id = ?
```

And this end up getting all the children where the join condition is not true.

So then I tried this

```
 @Query("select new Parent(p.id, p.name, c.id, c.date, c.name) from Parent p left join p.child c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth
```

And made this constructor

```
public Parent(int id, String name, int childId, LocalDate date, String childName) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.children = new HashMap<LocalDate, Child>();
    if (childId != null) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(id);
        child.setName(name);
        this.children.put(date, child);
    }
}
```

But the problem with this is I get a JSON array of length 4 when I want the top level of the array to be length 2, as there are only 2 parents in the DB currently.

How can I modify this to get the JSON payload that I want, which is posted at the top of the question.

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

Using the following doesn't work as child2 is not returned, if I were to pass in the date = '2021-01-01'

```
select distinct p from Parent p 
left join fetch p.children c 
where (YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMont) 
or c.parent is null
```

**EDIT 2 (about the auto generated query)**

I am running this as an API with spring boot, but there is no extra processing, here is my API and current query.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/parents/{date}", produces = { "application/json" })
@Operation(summary = "Get all parents for date")
public @ResponseBody List<Parent> getParentsByDate(@PathVariable("date") String dateString) {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate dateOccurred = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);

    return parentRepository.getParentsForDate(dateOccurred);


}
```

And then in my repository I just have my @Query and here is what I currently have in the `ParentRepository` class

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    @Query("select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children c where (YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth) or c.parent is null")
    public List<Parent> getParentsForDate(@Param("dateOccurred") LocalDate dateOccurred
}
```

But as said the problem with this is the null check does work correctly, if the parent has any children in another month, but not the current one the parent is not returned

Comment: On which field you join them? What does it mean on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear? Shouldn't be @Query("select p from Parent p left join p.child c on c.parent_id = p.id WHERE YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth?

Comment: @MrFisherman  I also always want to return the parent even if it has no children, which is why I LEFT OUTER JOIN on the child with the ON clause there, instead of have the WHERE YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth. I have updated the question with that

Comment: @iqueqiorio Please, can you indicate when the second query `select * from Child where c.parent_id = ?` is generated? I mean, do you process the entities in any way? Do you convert them to JSON, for instance?

Comment: @jccampanero the 2nd query is generated and runs after my Query annotation query, but there is nothing I am doing in my code to call it. I am using spring boot and believe this is generating it I have posted an 2nd edit

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to provide an answer with that information. Just one thing: are you using @Transactional in any way? If that is the case, can you please indicate where?

Comment: @jccampanero I have the @ Transactional annotation on a separate API in the same class, but not at the class so that should have no effect and thank you appreciate it!

Comment: @jccampanero update in question

Comment: Thank you. And please, how do the method `getParentsForDate` looks like in the repository? You mentioned that there is only the query, but you are passing `LocalDate` as argument, but in the query you use to variables for year an month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227307/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-jccampanero).

Comment: I am happy to see that you find a solution for your use case @iqueqiorio. I am sorry for not being able to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

---

I found solution for fetching and multi conditions for `join` operation:
We can apply `EntityGraph` feature:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Parent.children", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("children"))
public class Parent {
 ...
}
```

And in the repository, you need to link this `EntityGraph` with the `Query` like this:

```
...
@Query("select distinct p from Parent p left join p.children c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMont")
@EntityGraph(value = "graph.Parent.children")
List<Parent> findAllParents(Integer dateYear, Integer dateMont);
...
```

**Previous solution**:

---

As you know, Hibernate doesn't allow use more then one condition in `on` for `fetch join`, as result: `with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters` exception, therefore I propose to use the following HQL query:

```xml
select distinct p from Parent p 
left join fetch p.children c 
where (YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMont) 
or c.parent is null
```

**Note:** `distinct` is required for avoiding duplicates for parent entities, about that there is article: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-apply-distinct-to-jpql-but-not-sql-query/

As result, Hibernate will generate one query with supporting parents without children, if for children should be order as on posted json example, you need to add `@SortNatural` for `children` field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
@MapKey(name = "date")
@SortNatural
private Map<LocalDate, Child> children;
```

as result, the json will be the same as posted.

**As recommendation:** Don't use calculating values on runtime, for these operations index cannot be applied, in your case I propose to use virtual column(if Mysql) or separate indexed column only with prepared values for searching, and try to join tables by indexes, these recommendations will speed up your query execution.

Comment: Thank you for the response the problem with this is, if the parent has any children the is null part of the query isn't workin and doesn't return the parent

Comment: @iqueqiorio Sorry, I missed case with filtering, I updated answer, please see new approach for solving issue.

Comment: There are countless threads on Stackoverflow that deal with this problem (as displayed by the symptom `with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters`) and your solution with the EntityGraph is the only working one I could find. Well done!

Comment: Same here - appreciate for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query:

```java
@Query("select p from Parent p left join p.child c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth")
```

looks fine, it will return all the `Parent` entities independently if they have or not `children` as you need.

The problem is that afterwards, for any reason, probably when you serialize the information to JSON format, for every `parent` returned by the original query, the `OneToMany` relationship with `children` is being resolved. As a consequence, the second query you mentioned is executed and you obtain as a result `children` that does not meet the filter criteria.

Although it is unclear to me where your transactions demarcations are established, this may happen because when the entities are being serialized they are still associated with a persistence context - on the contrary, it will cause problems with lazy collection initialization.

One option you can try is detach those entities from the persistence context before serializing them.

To achieve that goal, first, include the `fetch` term in your query:

```java
@Query("select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth"
```

Unfortunately Spring Data does not provide an out of the box solution for detaching entities, but you can easily implement the necessary code.

First, define a base repository interface:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  void detach(T entity);
}
```

And its implementation:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public CustomRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public CustomRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(domainClass, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void detach(T entity) {
    this.entityManager.detach(entity);
  }

}
```

Now, create a factory bean for the new repository:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

public class CustomRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

  public CustomRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface) {
    super(repositoryInterface);
  }

  @Override
  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new CustomRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }

  private static class CustomRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public CustomRepositoryFactory(EntityManager em) {

      super(em);
      this.em = em;
    }

    protected <T, ID extends Serializable> SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata, EntityManager entityManager) {
      SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> repo = new CustomRepositoryImpl(metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
      return repo;
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      return CustomRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
  }

}
```

This factory must be registered in your `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class /* your other configuration */)
```

Your repository needs to implement the new one defined:

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends CustomRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    @Query("select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children c where (YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth) or c.parent is null")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Parent> getParentsForDate(@Param("dateOccurred") LocalDate dateOccurred)
}
```

Create a new service:

```java
public interface ParentService {
  List<Parent> getParentsForDate(LocalDate dateOccurred);
}
```

And the corresponding implementation:

```java
@Service
public class ParentServiceImpl implements ParentService {
  private final ParentRepository parentRepository;

  public ParentServiceImpl(ParentRepository parentRepository) {
    this.parentRepository = parentRepository;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<Parent> getParentsForDate(LocalDate dateOccurred) {
    Lis<Parent> parents = parentRepository.getParentsForDate(dateOccurred);

    // Now, the tricky part... I must recognize that I never tried
    // something like this, but I think it should work
    parents.forEach(parent -> parentRepository.detach(parent));
    return parents;
  }
}
```

And use the service in the controller:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/parents/{date}", produces = { "application/json" })
@Operation(summary = "Get all parents for date")
public @ResponseBody List<Parent> getParentsByDate(@PathVariable("date") String dateString) {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate dateOccurred = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);

    return parentService.getParentsForDate(dateOccurred);

}
```

I have not tested the code and I do not know if this way of detaching entities will work, but I think it will likely do.

If this approach does not work, my advice is that you try a different approach.

Instead of querying the parent, just filter the children directly and obtain the ones that match the filter criteria.

```java
@Query("select c from Child c on YEAR(c.date) = :dateYear and MONTH(c.date) = :dateMonth)
```

On the other hand, list all the `Parent`s (by using `findAll`, for instance), and create some kind of intermediate POJO, some DTO, to mix the information of the several results obtained, an return that information to the client:

```java
public class ParentDTO {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private Map<LocalDate, ChildDTO> children = Collections.emptyMap();

  // Setters and getters
}
```

```java
public class ChildDTO {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private LocalDate date;

  // Setters and getters
}
```

```java
  List<Child> children = /* the aforementioned query conforming to filter criteria */
  List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.findAll();

  List<ParentDTO> parentDTOs = new ArrayList(parents.size());
  for (Parent parent:parents) {
    ParentDTO parentDTO = new ParentDTO();
    parentDTOs.add(parentDTO);

    parentDTO.setId(parent.getId());
    parentDTO.setName(parent.getName());

    // Contains parent?
    if (children == null || children.isEmpty()) {
      continue;
    }

    Map<LocalDate, ChildDTO> childrenForThisParent = children.stream()
      .filter(child -> child.parent.equals(parent))
      .map(child -> {
        ChildDTO childDTO = new ChildDTO();
        childDTO.setId(child.getId());
        childDTO.setName(child.getName());
        childDTO.setDate(child.getDate());
        return childDTO;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getDate(), c));

    parentTO.setChildren(childrenForThisParent);
  }
```

The code is optimizable in several ways, but I hope you get the idea.