How to fetch inversely joined entities in a single query?
I have 2 entities, Student and Note:
@Entity
public class Student {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
  private Note note;
}

@Entity
public class Note {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
  private Student student;
}

If I try to fetch say 100 students using studentRepositoy::findAllById, Hibernate hits a in query and passes all the IDs. That's good but then it'll fire 100 queries more to get the note for each student. The FetchType.LAZY doesn't help here. I also tried FetchMode.JOIN and FetchMode.SELECT but they didn't solve the problem either.
Is there a way we could fetch the note along with the student. I mean this is just a simple example, but in production the parent class has multiple entities like Note that are inversely joined and while fetching 1000s of entries it is very time-consuming.
Thanks in Advance.

.. have you tried FetchType.EAGER?

Common practice here is to use LEFT JOIN FETCH. Consider changing or adding a method to your repository with custom query as follows:
// your repository here
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, UUID> { 
  // other methods in your repository
  // ...
  @Query(value = "SELECT s FROM Student s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.note") 
  List<Student> fetchAllStudentsWithNote(); 

'LEFT JOIN FETCH' does the work and keeps Fetch.Type = LAZY.

Tried SELECT s FROM Student s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.note WHERE s.division IN (:divisions)
SELECT s FROM Student s LEFT JOIN s.note WHERE s.division IN (:divisions)
SELECT s FROM Student s INNER JOIN s.note WHERE s.division IN (:divisions)
Still same result. Also tried changing FetchMode to EAGER.

I am not aware what Divisions are and so on. I just shared a common practice for your specific question. Consider checking this solution, the author gets extra request too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649418/hibernate-left-join-fetch-with-on-clause-or-alternative
